# boto3 can't connect to S3 from Docker container running in AWS batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ecs, aws-batch, amazon-ecr

I am attempting to launch a Docker container stored in ECR as an AWS batch job. The entrypoint python script of this container attempts to connect to S3 and download a file. 
I have attached a role with `AmazonS3FullAccess` to both the AWSBatchServiceRole in the compute environment and I have also attached a role with `AmazonS3FullAccess` to the compute resources.

This is the following error that is being logged: `botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"`

There is a chance that these instances are being launched in a custom VPC, not the default VPC. I'm not sure this makes a difference, but maybe that is part of the problem. I do not have appropriate access to check. I have tested this Docker image on an EC2 instance launched in the same VPC and everything works as expected.

Comment: Seems like a connection/firewall issue. If you cant check the Security Groups you should check inside your container a curl or telnet to these address.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned compute environment and compute resources. Did you add this S3 policy to the `Job Role` as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)?

> After you have created a role and attached a policy to that role, you can run tasks that assume the role. You have several options to do this:
>
> 1. Specify an IAM role for your tasks in the task definition. You can create a new task definition or a new revision of an existing task definition and specify the role you created previously. If you use the console to create your task definition, choose your IAM role in the Task Role field. If you use the AWS CLI or SDKs, specify your task role ARN using the taskRoleArn parameter. For more information, see Creating a Task Definition.
> 2. Specify an IAM task role override when running a task. You can specify an IAM task role override when running a task. If you use the console to run your task, choose Advanced Options and then choose your IAM role in the Task Role field. If you use the AWS CLI or SDKs, specify your task role ARN using the taskRoleArn parameter in the overrides JSON object. For more information, see Running Tasks.

Comment: Yes, I have the appropriate task roles set up. The issue ended up being that I was running a multinode batch job. Multinode batch jobs deploy the ecs containers with a network type of awsvpc. This network does not inherit the host network, it instead creates its own ENI which acts like a private network. In order to get it to work I had to create a NAT gateway, attach it to a private subnet(s), and deploy the EC2 batch nodes into that subnet and everything worked.